# Average of a Count in Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to solve this riddle. I have the following statement:

```
SELECT schedule_test.ID, LEFT(schedule_test.Course,2) AS 'Type', COUNT(*) AS  
'Count'
FROM schedule_test
GROUP BY ID, Type
```

It echos the following:

[image]

What can I add to the Select statement to add a 4th column with the average of the count for each Type? In other words, what was the average count of Type "HS" across all employees? Tried adding `AVG(COUNT(*))` but I get an error, `Invalid use of group function`.

Comment: you need to use `AVG` in multiple column but the `count` is a single value.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please give us your expected sample data .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT .......,
AVG(Count) AS average,
AVG(Count WHEN Type = 'HS' THEN Count ELSE NULL END) AS conditionalAverage
FROM schedule_test
GROUP BY ID, Type;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error...right syntax WHEN Type='HS' THEN Count ELSE NULL END). Also, your solution only sees Type="HS". Ideally, I would like average across all Types grouped by Type.